# Making few columns NULL based on a Where condition in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am working on a C# application where I an returning an entire data from an SQL data which certain criteria which can be explained using the following data

**Table1**

```
Id Term Location Bvol  Buser Bid Offer Ovol Ouser
1   Q1   Hou     100   dev   10   20   200   john
2   Q2   Hou     50    john  25   40   100   dev
3   Q2   Bea     1000  dev   30   45   2000  dev
```

I am trying to retrieve all the data related to a user named `dev` and I am comparing `dev` with both `Buser` and `Ouser` and I am trying to return `Id Term and Location` when atleast one of `Buser and Ouser` is matching with user `dev` but in case user `dev` is matching with `Buser` but not `Ouser` I only return `Bvol,Bid,Buser` along with `Id, Term and Location` and make `Offer,Ovol and Ouser as NULL` and same thing applies if a match is found with `Ouser`.

Expected Result is as follows

```
 Id Term Location    Bvol    Buser   Bid Offer Ovol Ouser
    1   Q1   Hou     100      dev    10   NUll NULL NULL
    2   Q2   Hou     NULL    NULL    NUll 40   100   dev
    3   Q2   Bea     1000     dev    30   45   2000  dev
```

To start with I have used the following Query when returned entire row if there is a match in either `Buser or Ouser`

```
 return db.BrokerOutrights.Where(b => b.BidBroker == 'dev'||
                                       b.OfferBroker=='dev');
```

**May I know a good way to achieve the earlier specified requirement?**

Comment: Try making the question more generic, so users can relate to it, it's a good question without stock exchange terms.

Answer (score 1):

It would possibly work with a Union:

Something along the lines of:

```
      var bids = db.BrokerOutrights
            .Where(b => b.BidBroker == 'dev')
            .Select(b => new { Id = b.Id, Term = b.Term, Location = b.Location, Bvol = b.Bvol, Buser = b.Buser, Bid = b.Bid, Offer = (int?)null, Ovol = (int?)null, Ouser = (string)null });

        var offers = db.BrokerOutrights
            .Where(b => b.OfferBroker == 'dev')
            .Select(b => new { Id = b.Id, Term = b.Term, Location = b.Location, Bvol = (int?)null, Buser = (string)null, Bid = (int?)null, Offer = b.Offer, Ovol = b.Ovol, Ouser = b.Ouser });

        return bids.Union(offers).Select(x => new BrokerOutright { Id = x.Id .... }).ToList();
```

The idea being to create two queries which project onto anonymous types; where the two anonymous types have the same signature, and can therefore be unioned.

You would then need to project the unioned queries back into your entity (BrokerOutright) and ToList the collection to run the query.

Answer (score 0):

The principle is simple, you must grow it

```
select (x == 'dev') ? value : null;
```

This could be done for every column

```
db.BrokerOutrights.Where(b => b.Buser == 'dev'|| b.Ouser=='dev')
.Select(i => new 
{
    i.Id, 
    i.Term, 
    i.Location, 
    (i.Buser == 'dev') ? i.Bvol : null, 
    (i.Buser == 'dev') ? i.Buser : null, 
    (i.Buser == 'dev') ? i.Bid: null, 
    (i.Ouser == 'dev') ? i.Offer : null, 
    (i.Ouser == 'dev') ? i.Ovol : null, 
    (i.Ouser == 'dev') ? i.Ouser : null
};
```